# UE4 - Get children widgets from UUserWidget's pointer (UMG)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-umg

I got my **non-UObject class** holds an

`UUserWidget* Instance;`

So how do I get a children widget (Ex: UTextBlock) out of that

Briefly, I want something like this:
`Instance->GetChildrenWidgetByName("UTextBlock_Name")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 4.26.2 you can do this if you know the child's name

```
Instance->WidgetTree->FindWidget(WidgetFName);
```

or this if you just want to find it by type

```
TArray<UWidget*> Children;
Instance->WidgetTree->GetAllWidgets(Children);
for(auto Child : Children)
{
    if(UTextBlock* Block = Cast<UTextBlock>(Child))
    {
       //return Block
       //or add to some TArray if you want to find multiple
    }
}
```

for more information take a look into [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/UMG/Blueprint/UWidgetTree/)

on a side note a very handy way of getting pointers to children of a widget is to use `meta = (BindWidget)` in `UPROPERTY` - more on that [here](https://benui.ca/unreal/ui-bindwidget/)